# Validating min and max length of a phone number according to select of country code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have phone number field with country code in drop-down, Now I want to validate Max length validation according to selection of country code in drop-down.

profile.rb

```
validates_length_of :phone, :minimum => 10, :maximum => 10 if country_code = 91
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that; `if` would evaluate at class definition, not at validation time. You either need to use `:if` option:

```
validates_length_of :phone, :minimum => 10, :maximum => 10,
    :if => Proc.new { |x| x.country_code == 91 }
```

or you need to use a custom validator, something like:

```
PHONE_LENGTH_LIMITS_BY_COUNTRY_CODE = {
  91 => [10, 10]
}
def phone_number_is_correct_according_to_country_code
  min, max = *PHONE_LENGTH_LIMITS_BY_COUNTRY_CODE[country_code]
  if phone.length < min || phone.length > max
    errors.add(:phone, "must be between #{min} and #{max} characters")
  end
end
validate :phone_number_is_correct_according_to_country_code
```

(Disclaimer: untested code)